# How to customize errors raising from mod_auth_openidc in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-auth-openidc

I'm using Apache with OIDC ( `mod_auth_openidc` ) binded with JWT

Problem is, if someone doesn't have access ( which is how the SSO works ) - I'm seeing a white page with a small text at the top left saying `you don't have permissions`.

How can I customize this page ?

This is my configuration:

```
          OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://myprovider.com/oauth2
          OIDCClientID            myclientid
          OIDCClientSecret        mysecret
          OIDCRedirectURI         https://myserver.com/auth/sso/callback
          OIDCCryptoPassphrase    mypassphrase
          OIDCHTTPTimeoutShort    6000

          OIDCSSLValidateServer Off
          OIDCSessionMaxDuration 84600
          OIDCScope "openid profile"

          <Location />
             AuthType openid-connect
             Require valid-user
          </Location>
```

Comment: https://github.com/OpenIDC/mod_auth_openidc/wiki#19-how-do-i-customize-the-user-facing-error-pages